# How do I update a column's offset in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetimeoffset

I converted a table's `DateTime` field to `DateTimeOffset`, but now the offset is automatically set to `+00:00`.

I need to change **all** `DateTimeOffset` fields of this table to an offset of +1:00.

How can I do this in an update query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `SWITCHOFFSET` to change the offset. You will need to subtract the amount of hours though from the date if you don't want the date to change.

```
SELECT  SWITCHOFFSET(DATEADD(hh, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATETIMEOFFSET)),
                         '+01:00')
```

Comment: Date and time should stay the same -- only the offset needs to change. Is this how I do it then?

Answer (score 7):

You can use TODATETIMEOFFSET(datetime, '+01:00' )
This wont affect the datetime part.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @t DATETIMEOFFSET

SELECT @t = Getdate()

SELECT Replace(@t, RIGHT(@t, 6), '+01:00') 

<update tablename set offsetfield = Replace(offsetfield, RIGHT(offsetfield, 6), '+01:00')>
```